# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Twitter Bootstrap Rendering Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Twitter's Bootstrap in an MVC 4 project, and it basically works, however the styling is off. For example, this is what a popover should look like:

[image]

However, the button renders incorrectly:

[image]

and the popover arrow is not aligned properly:

[image]

Any thoughts on what might be happening? Here is my .cshtml file:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")"></script>

<div class="well">  
<a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-danger" rel="popover" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">hover for popover</a>  
</div>  

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#example").popover();
    });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.. it was due to CSS conflicts with the default Site.css file.
`body` had a top border of 10 px, which was causing the misalignment of the popover
Also, i changed `<a` to a `<button` and the button rendered correctly.